# How to Select all polygons or lines that lie at least partially within a circle with a radius?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am storing OS Open Local data, as downloaded here: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html (top result).

In particular my geometry column takes one of two possible shapes:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geometry) FROM roads LIMIT 1;
```

Resulting in:

```
{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[464223.46,1213396.46],[464257.63,1213398.4],[464294.12,1213438.78],[464330.93,1213444.89]]}
```

And

```
 SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geometry) FROM buildings LIMIT 1;
```

Resulting in:

```
   {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[454003.53,1203047.09],[453984.86,1203083.28],[453997.27,1203089.71],[454015.96,1203053.49],[454003.53,1203047.09]]]}
```

Given a lat, a long, and a radius in meters, how would I SELECT all roads or buildings which are either contained by, or intersect the selected circle?

Comment: ST_Intersects with an Inner Join might be a faster approach see http://www.bostongis.com/postgis_intersection_intersects.snippet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the use of ST_Buffer/St_Intersects is really undesired here, I post another option with the use of only ST_DWithin. The advantage is a much faster and more correct than using ST_Buffer.
Also see Paul Ramsey`s [post](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2010/08/stintersects-and-stbuffer-no.html).

```
SELECT * 
FROM buildings AS b
WHERE ST_DWithin(b.geom,
  ST_Transform(
    ST_SetSrid(
      ST_MakePoint({longitude},{latitude})
      ,4326)
    ,27700)
,{radius})
```

Comment: So this query runs. But it returns no results. How would I go about debugging this query?

Comment: So what does the 4326 SRID mean? When I looked up my original .prj files (I imported .shp files from the same directories here):
http://prj2epsg.org/search
I get PROJCS["British_National_Grid",GEOGCS["GCS_OS.....
Running ` SELECT srid, proj4text FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE srtext LIKE '%British_National_Grid%';` produces two results,
27700 and 7405. Neither one of them fixes the query.

Comment: this should almost certainly be latitude, longitude in the make point