# How to Select an SRID? And how is it different from the SRID passed into ST_Transform?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, coordinate-system, srid, geofencing

Say I wanted to find geometries that intersect a circle at lat/long as outlined here [How to Select all polygons or lines that lie at least partially within a circle with a radius?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244160/how-to-select-all-polygons-or-lines-that-lie-at-least-partially-within-a-circle).

```
SELECT * 
FROM buildings AS b
WHERE ST_DWithin(b.geom,
  ST_Transform(
    ST_SetSrid(
      ST_MakePoint({longitude},{latitude})
      ,27700)
    ,27700)
,{radius})
```

Now my data was the OS Open Local data: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html (top result).

I've imported the `.shp` files.

Running the `.prj` through here: http://prj2epsg.org/search produces:

```
    PROJCS["British_National_Grid",GEOGCS["GCS_OSGB_1936",DATUM["D_OSGB_1936",
SPHEROID["Airy_1830",6377563.396,299.3249646]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",400000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",-100000.0],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-2.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996012717],
PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",49.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0],AUTHORITY["EPSG",27700]]
```

So in my postgis db I run:

```
SELECT srid FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE srtext LIKE '%British_National_Grid%';
```

Which produces two results:
27700 and 7405

By inspection the former corresponds exactly to my `.prj`

The query above, however, finds no results for any buildings in London (51.5236, -0.1047) irrespectively of radius size (500, 5000, 500000).

Additionally, dropping the `ST_SetSrid` produces:

```
ERROR:  Input geometry has unknown (0) SRID
```

Why doesn't the ST_Transform set the SRID as documented here: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html

Would I ever want the two SRID's to be distinct?

And why is the query not producing results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of your query:

```
ST_SetSrid(
  ST_MakePoint({longitude},{latitude})
  ,27700)
```

makes a point in OSGB (EPSG:27700) coordinates so 51.5,-0.1 is somewhere off the Scilly Isles (Britain's very own [Null Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island)). So you either need to create the point using the OS grid reference for London (554000,170000), or make the point in lat/lon using the SRID 4326 instead and then transform it to 27700 to match your data.

Comment: setting the srid to 4326 still returns no results.. What is SRID 4326?

Comment: ah yes, you will also need to use latitude, longitude as that is what 4326 is

Comment: still no results :/ Thanks for the explanation re 4326 though!

Comment: ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.1047, 51.5236), 4326), 27700) produces a point in clerkenwell in SRID 27700...if that doesn´t work, well, then your buildings are somewhere else (either in reality or because of another SRID) edit: ah you accepted, so it did work?